# Laravel 5.4 extend/ override \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to alter the behaviour of the `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File::getMimeType` method. Therefore I want to extend/ override the `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` class. How can I achieve this?

#### Update

This is the method I use to validate the file:

```
    public function meetsRequirements( UploadedFile $file ): bool {
        if ($file->getClientMimeType() === 'application/octet-stream') {

        }

        $validator = \Validator::make( [
            'file' => $file
        ], [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,tiff,psd,ai,eps,pdf'
        ] );

        if (
            $validator->fails() ||
            ! $this->hasMinimumDimensions( $file ) ||
            ! $this->hasMinimumDpi( $file )
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The eps extension is somehow translated to `application/octet-stream` mimetype when using the `getMimeType` method (which is probably used by the validator as well since `validator->fails()` returns `true`).
A `dd($file)` shows the mimetype `application/postscript`. So I want to edit the the `getMimeType` method so it returns the original mimetype instead of `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Can you please add some code where you use `file` class and where you need extend/override it. because it's make batter helpful for understood your issue!

Comment: @yashvantsinhzala I've updated my question